# How do you make a matplotlib funcanimation animation out of matplotlib.image.AxesImage objects?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a list of matplotlib.image.AxesImage objects that are the output of a fluid model. From what I can gather these are artists and so I should be able to iterate over them using FuncAnimation and make a movie.

However, so far this has not worked, where am I going wrong:

```
import matplotlib.animation as animation

# frames is a list of matplotlib.image.AxesImage objects

fig = plt.figure()

def animate(frame):
    art = [frames[frame]]
    return art

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,animate,frames=10)
ani.save('test_anim.mp4', fps=1, extra_args=['-vcodec', 'libx264'])
```

So far I am suspicious of defining the figure separately to the AxesImage objects and that I may not be returning the actual thing that can be iterated, similar to how you have to return line, in the line drawing case.

Edit1:

From what I understand so far, FuncAnimation works by calling the animation function you define which updates a particular artist (such as a line or AxisImage object). So my question should really be how to initialise and then update an AxisImage object in my scenario?

Edit2:

The answer of furas was very helpful, it turns out the real problem was that imshow does not take objects but rather the data from them. So you need frames[0].get_array!

What worked for me in the end was:

```
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import matplotlib as mpl

# frames is a list of matplotlib.image.AxesImage objects <- objects not data

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.gca()

draw_image = ax.imshow(frames[0].get_array(),animated=True)

def animate(frame):
    art = frames[frame].get_array()
    draw_image.set_array(art) 
    return draw_image

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,animate,frames=len(frames),blit=True,interval=25)
plt.show()
ani.save('SQGdemo1.mp4', fps=30, extra_args=['-vcodec', 'libx264'])
```

Because it's pretty here is what I was trying to make (see pyqg project on Github for the code):

[image: Surface Quasi-geostrophic equations see pyqg project on Github]

Comment: I think you need [sample](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/animation/simple_anim.html#sphx-glr-gallery-animation-simple-anim-py)

Comment: @r-beginners I have seen this before but don't quite understand how to apply it to my situation, have added an edit to the question.

Comment: first create any line or AxisImage on `plot` to have even static element for tests at start.

Comment: do you have to use `matplotlib` for video animation? See video animation with python module [manim](https://docs.manim.community/en/latest/examples.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

I use image [Lenna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenna) from Wikipedia.

---

You mentioned `matplotlib.image.AxesImage` so I load image with `Pillow` and generate list of rotated images with `matplotlib.image.pil_to_array()`

```
image = Image.open('/home/furas/test/lenna.png')

frames = [
    matplotlib.image.pil_to_array(image.rotate(-angle)) for angle in range(0, 360, 10)
]
```

I `animate()` I remove prevous image from axes, get new image from list and I draw it in axes. That's all.

```
def animate(number):

    # remove previous image
    ax.clear()
    
    # get new image from list
    art = frames[number % len(frames)]
    
    # display new image
    ax.imshow(art)

    #return (art,)  # I don't need it if I don't use `FuncAnimation(..., blit=True)`
```

I don't have to use `return` because I don't use `FuncAnimation(..., blit=True)` which gets elements and draw it faster - but I have to draw it on my own in animate.

---

Full code:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.image
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image


# frames is a list of matplotlib.image.AxesImage

image = Image.open('lenna.png')

frames = [
    matplotlib.image.pil_to_array(image.rotate(-angle)) for angle in range(0, 360, 10)
]    

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.gca()

def animate(frame):

    # remove previous image
    ax.clear()
    
    # get new image from list
    art = frames[frame % len(frames)]
    
    # display new image
    ax.imshow(art)

    #return art  # I don't need it if I don't use `FuncAnimation(..., blit=True)`

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=36)
plt.show()

#ani.save('animated_lenna.mp4', fps=5, extra_args=['-vcodec', 'libx264'])
ani.save('animated_lenna.gif', fps=5, writer='imagemagick')
```

---

[image]

I create random data for plot

```
plot_data_x = list(range(0, 501, 25))
plot_data_y = [randint(0, 500) for x in range(21)]
```

And in `animate()` I clear plot, remove first item from list, add new item at the end, and draw it again.

```
# remove all from ax
ax.clear()

# remove first item from list
plot_data_y.pop(0) 

# add last item on the list
plot_data_y.append(randint(0, 500)) 

# plot all again
ax.plot(plot_data_x, plot_data_y)
```

---

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.image
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
from random import randint

# frames is a list of matplotlib.image.AxesImage

image = Image.open('/home/furas/test/lenna.png')

frames = [
    matplotlib.image.pil_to_array(image.rotate(-angle)) for angle in range(0, 360, 10)
]    

plot_data_x = list(range(0, 501, 25))
plot_data_y = [randint(0, 500) for x in range(21)]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.gca()

def animate(frame):

    # remove all from ax
    ax.clear()
    
    # get new image from list
    art = frames[frame % len(frames)]
    
    # display new image
    ax.imshow(art)

    # remove first item from list
    plot_data_y.pop(0) 
    
    # add last item on list
    plot_data_y.append(randint(0, 500)) 
    
    # plot all again
    ax.plot(plot_data_x, plot_data_y)
    
    #return art  # I don't need it if I don't use `FuncAnimation(..., blit=True)`

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=36)
plt.show()

ani.save('animated_lenna_plot.mp4', fps=5, extra_args=['-vcodec', 'libx264'])
#ani.save('animated_lenna_plot.gif', fps=5, writer='imagemagick')
```

---

**EDIT:**

Version which uses `blit=True`

Previous version can also write so fast animation but it can't display it so fast.

[image]

I create plot and image at start to assign them to varaibles and later update data in this object and send them back with `return`. And later matplot draws it much fast with `blit=True`

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.image
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
from random import randint

# frames is a list of matplotlib.image.AxesImage

image = Image.open('/home/furas/test/lenna.png')

frames = [
    matplotlib.image.pil_to_array(image.rotate(-angle)) for angle in range(0, 360, 10)
]    

plot_data_x = list(range(0, 501, 25))
plot_data_y = [randint(0, 500) for x in range(21)]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.gca()

draw_image = ax.imshow(frames[0], animated=True)
draw_plot, = plt.plot(plot_data_x, plot_data_y)

def animate(frame):

    # remove all from ax
    #ax.clear()
    
    # get new image from list
    art = frames[frame % len(frames)]
    
    # display new image
    draw_image.set_array(art)

    # remove first item from list
    plot_data_y.pop(0) 
    
    # add last item on list
    plot_data_y.append(randint(0, 500)) 

    # update data in plot    
    #draw_plot.set_data(plot_data_x, plot_data_y)
    draw_plot.set_ydata(plot_data_y)
    
    return (draw_image, draw_plot) 
    
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=36, interval=25, blit=True)
plt.show()

ani.save('animated_lenna_plot_blit.mp4', fps=50, extra_args=['-vcodec', 'libx264'])
#ani.save('animated_lenna_plot_blit.gif', fps=50, writer='imagemagick')
```